# Como editar e avaliar tags de perguntas que entram em desacordo?

Tags: suporte, tags

A pergunta [Como resolver este “Erro na sintaxe”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148142/como-resolver-este-erro-na-sintaxe) tem as duas tags [portugol](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portugol) e [visualg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualg), entretanto o compilador (até na própria descrição do VisuAlg) não compila em Portugol e sim numa linguagem próxima. Porém, por ser pseudo-código, leva muitas pessoas a esse erro de interpretação.

Em casos assim como devemos agir quanto a edição das tags de perguntas? É válido remover uma das duas, deixar só a que possivelmente seja o compilador (vide que o AP não especificou nos comentários como solicitado) ou da linguagem que possivelmente não é a correta?

Comment: O ideal é ter certeza qual ele tá usando e editar as tags, pode fazer perguntando pro AP ou verificando o código dele caso ele tenha postado algum

Comment: @Math neste caso o Visualg compila em pseudo codigo também porém é descrito que nao é portugol, então como faria num caso assim foi feita uma edição após e adicionado a tag Visualg e aprovado, ou seja alguem com reputação suficiente aprovou

Comment: Acho q o Mauricio se enganou, o aprovador da edição provavelmente leu a msg da edição e acreditou nele para aprovar

Comment: Agora q eu vi que a pergunta é meio velha, dificilmente o AP vai responder, acho q nesse caso é melhor questionar o Mauricio sobre essa questão

Comment: Essas edições me fizeram a criar essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249294/64969 ; e pelo visto estou levando a crer que o Maurício está errado, com VisuAlg usando uma linguagem próxima porém derivada do Portugol, não a mesma. Mas também não assentei a pedra final na questão, então minhas conclusões são preliminares

Answer (score 1):

O autor da pergunta em questão não falou absolutamente nada sobre [visualg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualg). A pergunta dele era sobre [portugol](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portugol). Achar que a tag [visualg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualg) deveria ser aplicada só porque os dois são parecidos é o mesmo que querer aplicar a tag [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) em perguntas sobre [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) só porque são parecidos. Isso é incorreto.

O fato de alguém ter dado uma resposta com base em algo que poderia ser aplicado em uma tag diversa da que está na pergunta não significa que a tag deveria ser adicionada a pergunta.

O autor da pergunta alega o seguinte:

> Sempre obtenho: Erro na sintaxe

Entretanto, ele não diz qual ambiente de execução ele está usando para rodar isso. Como portugol é pseudocódigo, e ele está executando isso em algum lugar, então é de fundamental importância que ele diga onde isso está sendo executado. Existem várias implementações de Portugol por aí, o VisuAlg é apenas uma delas (talvez a mais popular de todas, mas não a única).

No entanto, ele não diz qual é o ambiente nem na pergunta, nem em nenhum comentário da pergunta e nem em nenhum comentário de nenhuma das respostas. E ele foi questionado sobre isso e mesmo assim não respondeu:

<kbd>[image: Qual erro de sintaxe e onde? Qual IDE de Portugol está usando]</kbd>

Ele deveria dizer isso para que a questão pudesse ser esclarecida, ainda mais se for considerado essa resposta deletada (visível só para quem tem 10000 pontos de reputação ou mais):

<kbd>[image: pois bem, executei aqui e funcionou ....]</kbd>

Mais de um ano se passou, e esse questionamento sobre qual é a IDE utilizada continua sem resposta! É extremamente improvável que o autor da pergunta reapareça para esclarecer isso. Logo, essa pergunta deveria ser fechada como **este não é um problema reproduzível ou é um erro de digitação** ou como **não está clara o suficiente**, uma vez que falta uma informação muito importante para que isso seja reproduzível e mesmo uma pessoa quem já tentou, não conseguiu reproduzir.

Deixando de lado o caso específico dessa pergunta, as tags devem ser aplicadas de acordo com a realidade da pergunta e do autor da pergunta. Se a pergunta é sobre um assunto X e um assunto Y, ela tem que receber as tags de X e de Y, e nunca uma tag sobre Z.

É verdade que muitos usuários, sejam eles os próprios autores das perguntas ou terceiros que venham a editá-las não colocam as tags corretas e muitas vezes é preciso um esforço significativo para tentar saber-se quais seriam as tags mais adequadas, sendo exatamente por esse motivo que muitas vezes erros na definição das tags acontecem.

Em especial eu já cometi o erro de tentar achar que a pergunta era de uma coisa e não era. Não achei o link, mas certa vez editei uma pergunta mal-formulada sobre [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) que falava sobre cálculos vetoriais que me parecia ser sobre [unity3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), e eu coloquei a tag do [unity3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) lá. Ocorre que o autor da pergunta na verdade estava usando uma outra biblioteca parecida, mas diferente, de forma que a minha edição para tentar ajudar acabou na verdade atrapalhando a todos. Obviamente, isso não teria acontecido se a pergunta fosse bem elaborada. A lição a ser aprendida é que no caso de dúvida, é melhor perguntar em um comentário do que tentar adivinhar, e se o autor da pergunta não responder ou não der uma resposta clara, que feche-se a pergunta para evitar-se que sejam postadas respostas que só irão ocasionar perda de tempo tanto de quem pergunta quanto de quem responde.

Voltando à pergunta específica, retirei a tag [visualg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualg) dela e votei para fechar.